# Sharepoint 2010 CSOM Get user and his groups by login name

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, user-profile

I want to get a user and all his groups by a login name.
Easy to do in Sharepoint 2013.

```
        clientContext.Load(site, l => l.RootWeb.SiteUsers, l => l.RootWeb.Id, l => l.Id);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var user = site.RootWeb.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(loginName);
        clientContext.Load(user, l => l.Groups, l => l.Id, l => l.LoginName);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

As both the SiteUsers as well as the Groups Property don't exist in SP2010 i have no idea how to accomplish this. 
Any ideas who i can get the needed information?

The only information i can use is the login name, CurrentUser or something similar won't work.

EDIT:
I have found a way to get the User object via CurrentUser, nevertheless i can't find a reliable way to get the groups for this user. 
I can iterate through all groups of the site and check if they contain the user. 
But then i have to also resolve all AD Groups and consider special AD Groups like "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users".
Makes the whole process rater slow. 
Is there a faster way to do this in SP2010?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the following approach to retrieve user groups using SharePoint **2010** CSOM:

- retrieve  site groups using [Web.SiteGroups Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.sitegroups(v=office.14).aspx)
- *exclude* those groups where user is not a member

**Example**

```
var user = site.RootWeb.CurrentUser;
var siteGroups = site.RootWeb.SiteGroups; 
ctx.Load(user);
ctx.Load(siteGroups, gcol => gcol.Include(g => g.LoginName,g => g.Users));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var userGroups = siteGroups.ToList().Where(g => g.Users.ToList().Exists(u => u.Id == user.Id)); //filter groups
```

Comment: here variable userGroups will return all properties of that groups?? Because I tried this code 2 days back, and I was not able to iterate through that collection and get any details of groups... Finally I followed different approach

Comment: Its loading all groups from site with all users... with big sharepoints with many groups and users per site  this will be a problematic performance hungry query, in fact it could get throttled by the server